# SwiftUI iOS 14 | auto expand textbox and content around in HStack

Tags: swiftui, ios14

Since the update to iOS14, the textbox is no longer expanded so that the arrows no longer adapt to the different lengths of text.
As shown in the gif, the text width remains and too long content is cut short with an ellipsis. Can you help me how to update my code?

[image: Example GIF]

```
    @State var teamName: [String] = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow"]

    […]

    HStack(spacing: 5) {
                            Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.left.fill")
                                .font(Font.system(size: 12 ,weight: .regular))
                            Text(teamName[selectedLeftTeam])
                                .font(Font.system(size: 24 ,weight: .bold, design: .monospaced).smallCaps())
                            Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.right.fill")
                                .font(Font.system(size: 12 ,weight: .regular))
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(Color("primaryColor")).opacity(0.2)
                    .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({
                            action in
                            self.swipeOffsetX = Double(action.translation.width * 0.75)
                        })
                        
                        .onEnded({
                            action in
                            
                            let left = self.swipeOffsetX < 30
                            let right = self.swipeOffsetX > 30
                            
                            if left { self.selectedLeftTeam += 1 }
                            if right { self.selectedLeftTeam -= 1 }

                            self.swipeOffsetX = 0 // reset
                        })
                        )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fixedSize` to make your `Text` use as much space as it's necessary:

```
Text(teamName[selectedLeftTeam])
    .font(Font.system(size: 24 ,weight: .bold, design: .monospaced).smallCaps())
    .fixedSize()
```

You can also limit it to one dimension only - if you want to do it horizontally:

```
.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
```

Comment: thanks very much. `.fixedSize()` worked perfectly!